# Flash Components in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I'm getting the error "could not resolve `<local:flashactionscript>` to a component implementation"....

This is my mxml code....

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
      layout="absolute" xmlns:local="com.*">
<local:flashactionscript x="400" y="400"/>
```

can anybody help me ?

Comment: flashactionscript is the name of actionscript class.

Comment: @shudha Is it places under `com` package?

Comment: yes, its under com package.
am trying to use flash components in flex application.
can anybody provide the url where i can learn how to use flash comp in flex

Comment: So the fully-qualified name of your class is com.flashactionscript?

Answer (score 0):

flashactionscript is the name of actionscript class.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Image tag and set its source to a flash movie like so:

`<mx:Image source="assets/yourFlash.swf"/>`

link: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/Image.html